# How to do specify level depth (or axis) for outer in Python 2.7?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to get Python 2.7 to perform this operation (I present the example in Mathematica because I know how to do it there). Basically I have a list of many 3D vectors, i.e., an array n*3 (here I use n=4, but in my problem n can be several hundreds or more; I am looking for speed, something faster than 'looping'):

```
Input:
vecs = {{ax, ay, az}, {bx, by, bz}, {cx, cy, cz}, {dx, dy, dz}};
```

I want to form the array of all the differences between any two of these vectors. This would be an array n*n*3. The key thing is to tell outer to stop breaking things into components at a certain level:

```
Input:
diff = Outer[Subtract, vecs, vecs, 1]

Output:
{{{0, 0, 0}, 
  {ax - bx, ay - by, az - bz},
  {ax - cx, ay - cy, az - cz},
  {ax - dx, ay - dy, az - dz}},
 {{-ax + bx, -ay + by, -az + bz},
  {0, 0, 0},
  {bx - cx, by - cy, bz - cz},
  {bx - dx, by - dy, bz - dz}},
 {{-ax + cx, -ay + cy, -az + cz},
  {-bx + cx, -by + cy, -bz + cz}, 
  {0, 0, 0}, 
  {cx - dx, cy - dy, cz - dz}},
 {{-ax + dx, -ay + dy, -az + dz},
  {-bx + dx, -by + dy, -bz + dz},
  {-cx + dx, -cy + dy, -cz + dz},
  {0, 0, 0}}}
```

Basically, I do not want to subtract all possible combinations, only x-components with x-components, etc. This is very common in physics and when I read the documentation of the numpy array functions I get the impression I am staring at the answer, but I just cannot see how to implement in Python that last '1' in the Mathematica Outer command. If I don't use that last '1' in Mathematica, then I would get a larger array, which is what I am getting in Python now.

Thanks in advance,

OL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can just use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by extending `vecs` to a 3D array such that the second axis is a singleton dimension and thus when the original 2D version is subtracted from it, you would have the expected 3D array of shape `n x n x 3`. This efficient vectorized solution would look something like this -

```
vecs[:,None,:] - vecs
```

Verify output -

```
In [318]: vecs
Out[318]: 
array([[1, 4, 8],    # {ax, ay, az}
       [7, 8, 7],    # {bx, by, bz}
       [1, 4, 8],    # {cx, cy, cz}
       [4, 3, 1]])   # {dx, dy, dz}

In [319]: vecs.shape
Out[319]: (4, 3)

In [320]: vecs[:,None,:] - vecs
Out[320]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0],  # {0, 0, 0}
        [-6, -4,  1],  # {ax - bx, ay - by, az - bz}
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [-3,  1,  7]],

       [[ 6,  4, -1],
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [ 6,  4, -1],
        [ 3,  5,  6]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0],
        [-6, -4,  1],   # {-bx + cx, -by + cy, -bz + cz}
        [ 0,  0,  0],
        [-3,  1,  7]],

       [[ 3, -1, -7],
        [-3, -5, -6],
        [ 3, -1, -7],   # {-cx + dx, -cy + dy, -cz + dz},
        [ 0,  0,  0]]]) # {0, 0, 0}

In [321]: (vecs[:,None,:] - vecs).shape
Out[321]: (4, 4, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar, I will give this a try and definitely let you know. From the output you post, this looks promising.

Comment: @OttoLinsuain Sure! Let me know when you can!